# how to qualitatively evaluate word embeddings?

Tags: natural-language, model-evaluation, metric, word2vec, word-embeddings

I have a bunch of word embedding models trained on a corpus. I want to do qualitative analysis of the words for a research paper. 
I have the following in mind:

```
1. sample 5-10 words 
2. get "most similar" five words for these sample words.
3. Ask some reviewers to rate each word from these "most similar" as similar from a scale of 1-10 
  (1 being least similar and 10 being most similar)
4. Take average of ratings provided by these reviewers. The highest average ratings means best model.
```

I want to know if there are any other more sophisticated metrics than taking average of ratings. (Also, NDCG can't be applied as this not a classification or IR problem.)

I would also appreciate if there someone can point to other qualitative evaluation techniques based on word similarity, other than plotting word vectors or semantic tasks as in Word2Vec paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My task at hand was binary classification (-1/+1). In order to do qualitative analysis of trained word embeddings, I plotted probability distributions of +1 class. Ideally, for all +1 labels, the probability distribution should be a bar where probability is 1 and for all -1 labels, the probability distribution should be a bar where probability is zero.